# IE8 Array and indexOf conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently use jquery 1.8.3. I think it added `indexOf` to `Array.prototype` so now every of my array always contains the method indexOf as the first element. 
Doing `for (var i in object)` I always get the method infexOf as my first element and it bugged my code.

Bug happened on IE8 only.

What I want is to remove this indexOf from all arrays or anyway to hack jquery / resolve this problem.

PS: I'm not even sure if it's jquery is the cause of this problem

Thanks.

Comment: jQuery does not add anything to native objects. It must come from somewhere else. You should not use `for...in` to iterate over arrays anyway (see the [MDN description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Description) (second yellow box)). Use a `for` loop or jQuery's `$.each`.

Comment: `Array.indexOf` is not implemented in IE8 and I don't think jQuery adds it either. [See compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: I just checked the source, JQuery definitely does not add `indexOf`.

Comment: Prototype does, however.

Comment: jQuery provides `$.inArray()` rather than hacking the Array prototype. I guess this is coming from a different library. (you might want to look into this -- it's not ideal to be including jQuery and Prototype in the same page; it's a bit of a waste of bandwidth as they both do similar things)

Comment: @Spudley yes, I checked it doesn't come from jQuery. It's from other people's badly coded plugin. You'd be amazed how IE8 handle this loop stuff differently with FF and Chrome.

Comment: @ThanhTrung - it really isn't IE8's fault this time. If the `indexOf` is added to the Array prototype in a way that shows up in `for...in` loops, then that's the fault of the plugin code, not IE. Okay, yes, it's a bad thing that IE doesn't have the `indexOf` feature in the first place, but that's just because it's an old browser; its behaviour once the `indexOf` function is added is perfectly in line with normal javascript behaviour.

Comment: @ThanhTrung - I've combined all the above, plus the actual best solution into a new answer to the question. See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer here is that you shouldn't be using a `for(...in...)` loop to iterate an Array in Javascript.

The whole point of having an Array is that it has a numbered sequence of elements, so you should be using a `for()` loop.

```
for(var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
     //do stuff here with myArray[i]
}
```

That alone will resolve the issue in this case, because it will only iterate the numbered elements, so the `indexOf` method won't get involved.

However, a brief explaination of the problem with `for(..in..)` here may be helpful, so let me explain...

The underlying cause of the error you're seeing is because the `indexOf` method isn't supported for arrays in IE8, so something in your code (not jQuery though) has added it to the Array prototype.

This in turn means that when you do a `for(..in..)` loop, it will be picked up as one of the elements to be iterated.

In this case, you have a better solution (the `for()` loop; see above), but in cases where you really do need to use a `for(..in..)` loop, this can be a real problem. You can prevent this by checking `hasOwnProperty()` immediately inside your `for(..in..)` loop. This function returns `false` for items that are part of the object prototype, so it helps you avoid hitting unwanted methods when looping an object.

This is considered best practice for every `for(..in..)` loop. In fact, if you use a tool like [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/), to check your coding style, it will complain if you don't do this.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from not using `for...in` to iterate over an array, if you must use `for...in`, then combine it with `hasOwnProperty` to tell if the property you are looking at really belongs to the object in question, or came from the prototype:

```
for (var prop in myObject) {
    if (myObject.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        // this didn't come from the prototype.
    }
}
```